# New Codename One bare-bones project to start a new project

Tags: codenameone

I have now noticed a radical change in the source Java code obtained via https://start.codenameone.com/

Obviously I'm used to coding with init(), start(), stop(), destroy() methods, I don't know how to handle this new code. Is it documented somewhere? I didn't see anything in the blog. Thank you

Lifecycle's javadoc (https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/system/Lifecycle.html) is not very helpful. It just states:

> Optional helper class that implements the Codename One lifecycle
> methods with reasonable default implementations to help keep sample
> code smaller.

So the following code is just an example that I need to remove, and then manually insert the usual init(), start(), stop() and destroy() methods?

```
public class MyDownloader extends Lifecycle {
    @Override
    public void runApp() {
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        Button helloButton = new Button("Hello World");
        hi.add(helloButton);
        helloButton.addActionListener(e -> hello());
        hi.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Hello Command",
        FontImage.MATERIAL_CHECK, 4, e -> hello());
        hi.show();
    }

    private void hello() {
        Dialog.show("Hello Codename One", "Welcome to Codename One", "OK", null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed here: https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/opifd6/a_new_approach_for_the_lifecycle_main_class/

Notice the lifecycle methods still exist and you can override them if you want but for the most part you don't really need to:

> When we started Codename One we copied the convention in Java of
> having a very verbose lifecycle class. This seemed like a good and
> powerful approach when we just started. The thing about core decisions
> like that is that you end up accepting them as dogma even when you
> yourself made them.
>
> That was just stupid and with my recent [commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/a0b0e102a8772f7a0bdd6cfeb87a1e39244dfb5d) this should be fixed.
> With this your main class can derive from the new Lifecycle object and
> you would be able to remove a lot of boilerplate. E.g. this would be
> the new "Hello World":

```
public class MyApp extends Lifecycle {
    public void runApp() {
        Form hello = new Form("Hello", BoxLayout.y());
        hello.add(new Label("Hello World"));
        hello.show();
    }
}
```

> That removes a lot of the stuff most of us don't touch in the
> lifecycle class while still allowing us to customize it if we need to
> do that.